# Problems logging in Stack Overflow with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, login, firefox

I can't log in to Stack Overflow with Firefox (20.0.1) or Chrome. I tried under Ubuntu and Windows 7 and allowed all third party cookies in Firefox. I am actually able to insert all necessary login data like username and password but after clicking the **Sign in** button the actual page won't load. Instead I am stuck at the login page.

I couldn't believe that IE 10 (not very updated) hasn't any problems. I guess the JavaScript is not loading the page. But what could block it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an idiot... The problem was that the date and time on the system was incorrect. Thus the certificates and cookies were not valid. After updating the system date and time I was able to log in.

Comment: Why would IE not cause a problem?

Comment: IE is at least giving me the option to continue even untrusted page...  firefox just leave the login vanished after submiting... I actually found out in stackoverflow login history that I was logged in even with firefox but it still shew the login tag in the question board

Comment: My date and time are correct, but it still fails.